# Shell script not recognizing JAVA_HOME env variable

Tags: bash, java

```
gandalf@AS426:~$
gandalf@AS426:~$ cd /xnc

gandalf@AS426:/xnc$ sudo ./runxnc.sh
[sudo] password for gandalf:
Need to set JAVA_HOME environment variable

gandalf@AS426:/xnc$ echo $JAVA_HOME
/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle/

gandalf@AS426:/xnc$ echo $PATH
/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle/

gandalf@AS426:/xnc$ more runxnc.sh
#!/bin/bash

platform='unknown'
unamestr=`uname`
if [[ "$unamestr" == 'Linux' ]]; then
   platform='linux'
elif [[ "$unamestr" == 'Darwin' ]]; then
   platform='osx'
fi

cd `dirname $0`
if [[ $platform == 'linux' ]]; then
   fullpath=`readlink -f $0`
elif [[ $platform == 'osx' ]]; then
   TARGET_FILE=`basename $0`

   # Iterate down a (possible) chain of symlinks
   while [ -L "$TARGET_FILE" ]
   do
       TARGET_FILE=`readlink "$TARGET_FILE"`
       cd `dirname $TARGET_FILE`
       TARGET_FILE=`basename "$TARGET_FILE"`
   done

   # Compute the canonicalized name by finding the physical path
   # for the directory we're in and appending the target file.
   PHYS_DIR=`pwd -P`
   RESULT="$PHYS_DIR/$TARGET_FILE"
   fullpath="$RESULT"

[[ -z ${JAVA_HOME} ]] && [[ -x "/usr/libexec/java_home" ]] && export JAVA_HOME=`/usr/libexec/java_home -v 1.7`;

fi

[[ -z ${JAVA_HOME} ]] && echo "Need to set JAVA_HOME environment variable" && exit -1;
[[ ! -x ${JAVA_HOME}/bin/java ]] && echo "Cannot find an executable \
JVM at path ${JAVA_HOME}/bin/java check your JAVA_HOME" && exit -1;

basedir=`dirname "${fullpath}"`

function usage {
    echo "Usage: $0 [-tls] [-tlskeystore <keystore>] [-tlstruststore <truststore>] [-jmx] [-jmxport <num>] [-debug] [-debugsuspend] [-debugport <num>] [-start [<console port>]] [-stop] [-status] [-console] [-osgiPasswordSync] [-help] [-p
ipeout] [<other args will automatically be used for the JVM>]"
    exit 1
}

if [ ! -d "${basedir}/work" ]; then
  mkdir "${basedir}/work"
fi

pidfile="${basedir}/work/xnc.pid"
debug=0
debugsuspend=0
debugport=8000
debugportread=""
startdaemon=1
daemonport=2400
daemonportread=""
jmxport=1088
jmxportread=""
startjmx=0
stopdaemon=0
statusdaemon=0
consolestart=0
dohelp=0
starttls=0
tlskeystore=""
tlstruststore=""
keystoresystempropertyspecified=0
truststoresystempropertyspecified=0
pipeout=0
extraJVMOpts="-server -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -mx1024m -XX:MaxPermSize=256m"
unknown_option=0
passwordprompt=0
while true ; do
    case "$1" in
        -tls) starttls=1; shift ;;
        -tlskeystore) shift; tlskeystore="$1"; shift ;;
        -tlstruststore) shift; tlstruststore="$1"; shift ;;
        -debug) debug=1; shift ;;
        -jmx) startjmx=1; shift ;;
        -debugsuspend) debugsuspend=1; shift ;;
        -debugport) shift; debugportread="$1"; if [[ "${debugportread}" =~ ^[0-9]+$ ]] ; then debugport=${debugportread}; shift; else echo "-debugport expects a number but was not found"; exit -1; fi;;
        -jmxport) shift; jmxportread="$1"; if [[ "${jmxportread}" =~ ^[0-9]+$ ]] ; then jmxport=${jmxportread}; shift; else echo "-jmxport expects a number but was not found"; exit -1; fi;;
        -start) startdaemon=1; consolestart=0; shift; daemonportread="$1"; if [[ "${daemonportread}" =~ ^[0-9]+$ ]] ; then daemonport=${daemonportread}; shift; fi;;
        -stop) stopdaemon=1; shift ;;
        -status) statusdaemon=1; shift ;;
        -console) consolestart=1; startdaemon=0; shift ;;
        -help) dohelp=1; shift;;
        -pipeout) pipeout=1; shift;;
        -DcontrollerKeyStore*) extraJVMOpts="${extraJVMOpts} $1"; keystoresystempropertyspecified=1; shift;;
        -DcontrollerTrustStore*) extraJVMOpts="${extraJVMOpts} $1"; truststoresystempropertyspecified=1; shift;;
        -D*) extraJVMOpts="${extraJVMOpts} $1"; shift;;
        -X*) extraJVMOpts="${extraJVMOpts} $1"; shift;;
        -verbose:*) extraJVMOpts="${extraJVMOpts} $1"; shift;;
        -javaagent:*) extraJVMOpts="${extraJVMOpts} $1"; shift;;
        -osgiPasswordSync) passwordprompt=1; shift ;;
        "") break ;;
        *) echo "Unknown option $1"; unknown_option=1; shift ;;
    esac
done

# Unknown Options and help
if [ "${unknown_option}" -eq 1 ]; then
    usage
fi

if [ "${dohelp}" -eq 1 ]; then
    usage
fi

# Validate Java version
_java="$JAVA_HOME/bin/java"
if [[ "$_java" ]] && [[ "${stopdaemon}" -eq 0 ]] && [[ "${statusdaemon}" -eq 0 ]]; then
    version=$("$_java" -version 2>&1 | awk -F '"' '/version/ {print $2}')
    if [[ "$version" < "1.7" ]]; then
        echo "Error: Current Java version is $version. Required Java version is 1.7 or above. For latest security fixes recommended Java version is 1.8.0_45 or above. Please upgrade current Java version and restart Nexus Data Broker."
        exit -1
    elif [[ "$version" < "1.8.0_45" ]]; then
        echo "Warning: Current Java version is $version, Latest security fixes require Java version 1.8.0_45 or above, Upgrade to 1.8.0_45 or above is recommended"
    fi
fi

# Validate debug port
if [[ "${debugport}" -lt 1024 ]] || [[ "${debugport}" -gt 65535 ]]; then
    echo "Debug Port not in the range [1024,65535] ${debugport}"
    exit -1
fi

# Validate daemon console port
if [[ "${daemonport}" -lt 1024 ]] || [[ "${daemonport}" -gt 65535 ]]; then
    echo "Daemon console Port not in the range [1024,65535] value is ${daemonport}"
    exit -1
fi

# Validate jmx port
if [[ "${jmxport}" -lt 1024 ]] || [[ "${jmxport}" -gt 65535 ]]; then
    echo "JMX Port not in the range [1024,65535] value is ${jmxport}"
    exit -1
fi

# Debug options
if [ "${debugsuspend}" -eq 1 ]; then
    extraJVMOpts="${extraJVMOpts} -Xdebug -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=y,address=${debugport}"
elif [ "${debug}" -eq 1 ]; then
    extraJVMOpts="${extraJVMOpts} -Xdebug -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=n,address=${debugport}"
fi

# Add JMX support
if [ "${startjmx}" -eq 1 ]; then
    extraJVMOpts="${extraJVMOpts} -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=${jmxport} -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote"
fi

#Add TLS support
keystoredefault="${basedir}/configuration/tlsKeyStore"
truststoredefault="${basedir}/configuration/tlsTrustStore"
if [ "${starttls}" -eq 1 ]; then
    extraJVMOpts="${extraJVMOpts} -DsecureChannelEnabled=true"

    if [ "${tlskeystore}" == "" ]; then
        if [ "${keystoresystempropertyspecified}" -eq 0 ]; then
            echo "The location of the TLS KeyStore is not provided. Use default ${keystoredefault}"
            extraJVMOpts="${extraJVMOpts} -DcontrollerKeyStore=${keystoredefault}"
        fi
    else
        extraJVMOpts="${extraJVMOpts} -DcontrollerKeyStore=${tlskeystore}"
    fi

    if [ "${tlstruststore}" == "" ]; then
        if [ "${truststoresystempropertyspecified}" -eq 0 ]; then
            echo "The location of the TLS TrustStore is not provided. Use default ${truststoredefault}"
            extraJVMOpts="${extraJVMOpts} -DcontrollerTrustStore=${truststoredefault}"
        fi
    else
        extraJVMOpts="${extraJVMOpts} -DcontrollerTrustStore=${tlstruststore}"
    fi
    echo ""
fi

# Initialize OSGi console password to non-default
if [[  "${startdaemon}" -eq 1 || "${consolestart}" -eq 1 ]] && [ "${statusdaemon}" -eq 0 ] && [ "${stopdaemon}" -eq 0 ] && [ "${passwordprompt}" -eq 1 ]; then
    passvar=
    echo "If XNC password is changed, OSGi webconsole password needs to be changed, to set non-default OSGi webconsole password Enter"
    read -p 'XNC Admin Password [default]: ' passvar
    if [[ ! -z "$passvar" ]]; then
        extraJVMOpts="${extraJVMOpts} -Dfelix.webconsole.password=${passvar}"
    fi
fi

########################################
# Now add to classpath the OSGi JAR
########################################
CLASSPATH="${basedir}/lib/org.eclipse.osgi-3.8.1.v20120830-144521.jar"
FWCLASSPATH="file:${basedir}/lib/org.eclipse.osgi-3.8.1.v20120830-144521.jar"

########################################
# Now add the extensions
########################################

# Extension 1: this is used to be able to convert all the
# bundleresouce: URL in file: so packages that are not OSGi ready can
# still work. Notably this is the case for spring classes
CLASSPATH="${CLASSPATH}:${basedir}/lib/org.eclipse.virgo.kernel.equinox.extensions-3.6.0.RELEASE.jar"
FWCLASSPATH="${FWCLASSPATH},file:${basedir}/lib/org.eclipse.virgo.kernel.equinox.extensions-3.6.0.RELEASE.jar"

########################################
# Now add the launcher
########################################
CLASSPATH="${CLASSPATH}:${basedir}/lib/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher-1.3.0.v20120522-1813.jar"
FWCLASSPATH="${FWCLASSPATH},file:${basedir}/lib/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher-1.3.0.v20120522-1813.jar"

if [ "${stopdaemon}" -eq 1 ]; then
    if [ -e "${pidfile}" ]; then
        daemonpid=`cat "${pidfile}"`
        ps -p ${daemonpid} > /dev/null
        if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
            kill "${daemonpid}"
            echo "Controller with PID: ${daemonpid} -- Stopped!"
        else
            echo "Controller with PID: ${daemonpid} -- Doesn't seem to exist"
        fi
        rm -f "${pidfile}"
        exit 0
    else
        daemonpid=`ps -ef | grep '[-]Dosgi.install.area=' | awk '{print $2}'`
        if [ ! -z "$daemonpid" ]; then
            kill "${daemonpid}"
            echo "Controller with PID: ${daemonpid} -- Stopped!"
            exit 0
        else
            echo "Doesn't seem any Controller daemon is currently running"
            exit -1
        fi
    fi
fi

if [ "${statusdaemon}" -eq 1 ]; then
    if [ -e "${pidfile}" ]; then
        daemonpid=`cat "${pidfile}"`
        ps -p ${daemonpid} > /dev/null
        if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
            echo "Controller with PID: ${daemonpid} -- Running!"
            exit 0
        else
            echo "Controller with PID: ${daemonpid} -- Doesn't seem to exist"
            rm -f "${pidfile}"
            exit 0
        fi
    else
        daemonpid=`ps -ef | grep '[-]Dosgi.install.area=' | awk '{print $2}'`
        if [ ! -z "$daemonpid" ]; then
            echo "Controller with PID: ${daemonpid} -- Running!"
            exit 0
        else
            echo "Doesn't seem any Controller daemon is currently running"
            exit -1
        fi
    fi
fi

if [ "${startdaemon}" -eq 1 ]; then
    if [ -e "${pidfile}" ]; then
        echo "Another instance of controller running, check with $0 -status"
        exit -1
    fi
    # create a pipe to redirect output
    if [ "${pipeout}" -eq 1 ]; then
        stdoutPipe="${basedir}/work/xncpipe"
        if [[ ! -e "${stdoutPipe}" ]]; then
            mkfifo "${basedir}/work/xncpipe" || stdoutPipe="/dev/null"
        fi
    else
        # regular pipeing
        stdoutPipe="/dev/null"
    fi

    $JAVA_HOME/bin/java ${extraJVMOpts} \
        -Djava.io.tmpdir="${basedir}/work/tmp" \
        -Dosgi.install.area="${basedir}" \
        -Dosgi.configuration.area="${basedir}/configuration" \
        -Dosgi.frameworkClassPath="${FWCLASSPATH}" \
        -Dosgi.framework="file:${basedir}/lib/org.eclipse.osgi-3.8.1.v20120830-144521.jar" \
        -Dosgi.console.ssh=${daemonport} \
        -Djava.awt.headless=true \
        -Dinteractive=0 \
        -classpath "${CLASSPATH}" \
        org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main \
        -consoleLog > "${stdoutPipe}" 2>&1 &
    daemonpid=$!
    echo ${daemonpid} > ${pidfile}
    echo "Running controller in background with PID: ${daemonpid}, to connect to it please SSH to this host on port ${daemonport}"
elif [ "${consolestart}" -eq 1 ]; then
    if [ -e "${pidfile}" ]; then
        echo "Another instance of controller running, check with $0 -status"
        exit -1
    fi
    $JAVA_HOME/bin/java ${extraJVMOpts} \
        -Djava.io.tmpdir="${basedir}/work/tmp" \
        -Dosgi.install.area="${basedir}" \
        -Dosgi.configuration.area="${basedir}/configuration" \
        -Dosgi.frameworkClassPath="${FWCLASSPATH}" \
        -Dosgi.framework="file:${basedir}/lib/org.eclipse.osgi-3.8.1.v20120830-144521.jar" \
        -Djava.awt.headless=true \
        -Dinteractive=1 \
        -classpath "${CLASSPATH}" \
        org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main \
        -console \
        -consoleLog
fi
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

sudo starts the process in a new environment which is by default reset before the command is run.

If the machine admin hasn't disallowed it in /etc/sudoers you can use `sudo -E command` to preserve the user's environment variables for the command.

Answer (score 1):

Although, there are many ways, you can simply follow these steps:

1. `sudo vi /etc/environment`
2. Add your env variable in the file: `JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle/`
3. `source /etc/environment`
4. Now, `$JAVA_HOME` would be accessible for all users.
5. Execute your script: `sudo sh runxnc.sh`

Comment: It does not work for me

Answer (score 0):

Since you are running the script in sudo it is not going to take env variable you set in gandalf user. Maybe adding the env variable to /root/.bashrc can help!